# How to import Python library in redash

Tags: python

I add Python as data source in redash,
but when import 'MySQL.connector' module I get an error:

I followed this article:
http://kzkohashi.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/12/09/224516

```
def read_sql(): 
    import mysql.connector
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="******",database="testing")
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("select hour,sum(temperature) as temperature ,sum(wind_speed) as wind_speed from weatherdaat group by hour")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in myresult: 
       print(x[0],x[1],x[2])  
read_sql()
```

I get this error

> Error running query: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'module'
>   object has no attribute 'connector'

Answer (score 0):

The installation seems broken.

Try this:

```
pip uninstall mysql-connector
pip uninstall mysql-connector-python
```

Then this:

```
pip install mysql-connector
# OR
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

And then:

```
import mysql.connector
```

Comment: See my edited post. Try to uninstall and then install again.

Comment: i do that the problem is still , in jupyter notebook code run correctly but in redash error appear

Comment: you should report your problem here then: https://github.com/getredash/redash/issues